# JPA One-to-Many relationship using a List - OrderBy ignored/not working

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'll try to formulate the question more simple:

```
@Entity
public class One implements Serializable {
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@OneToMany
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private List<Many> many;
...
```

First I populate the List with some Many-Entities and persist the One-Entity. Second I retrieve (em.find) the One-Entity expecting the List in ascending order by Many#name, but it's not ordered by name. The List is ordered by id. Complete code see below if necessary.

**Original post some days ago:**

I'm using a current Netbeans Glassfish bundle.

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.51-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_51-b13
System: Mac OS X version 10.9.3 running on x86_64; UTF-8; de_DE (nb)

The JPA @OrderBy annotation is completely ignored.

```
@Entity
public class One implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private List<Many> many;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Many> getMany() {
        return many;
    }

    public void setMany(List<Many> many) {
        this.many = many;
    }

}
```

The many Entity

```
@Entity
public class Many implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Many() {
    }

    public Many(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The service class (EJB)

```
@Stateless
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cwPU")
    private EntityManager em;


    public One createOne() {
        return em.merge(new One());
    }

    public Many createMany(String name) {
        return em.merge(new Many(name));
    }

    public One add(Long oneId, Long manyId) {
        One one = em.find(One.class, oneId);
        Many many = em.find(Many.class, manyId);
        one.getMany().add(many);
        return one;
    }

    public One find(Long id) {
        One one = em.find(One.class, id);
        return one;
    }

}
```

The main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        Context ctx = container.getContext();
        Service service = (Service) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/Service");
        One one = service.createOne();
        Many many = service.createMany("the-first");
        service.add(one.getId(), many.getId());
        many = service.createMany("a-second");
        one = service.add(one.getId(), many.getId());
        one = service.find(one.getId());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        for (Many m : one.getMany()) {
            System.out.println(m.getName());
        }
        container.close();
    }

}
```

The output:

```
the-first
a-second
```

No matter what I write to the @OrderBy annotation (name ASC, name DESC, id ASC, id DESC), the output is always the same ascending order by the id.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is calling em.refresh (at the right place) as stated from Chris and WPrecht. I had to do this in a separate EJB method.

This did **not** work:

```
public One find(Long id) {
    em.refresh(em.find(One.class, id)); // did not work
    One one = em.find(One.class, id);
    return one;
}
```

Adding a separate refresh method

```
public void refresh(Long id) {
    em.refresh(em.find(One.class, id));
}
```

and calling it in the main program

```
...
service.refresh(one.getId());
one = service.find(one.getId());
...
```

works!

Probably I have to do more reading to understand caching.

Comment: I am using EclipseLink 2.6.0. em.refresh(entity) does the job for me, too (em.find(class,id) was not enough to get the ordering applied)  - thank You for Your hint.

Answer (score 4):

The `@Orderby` annotation doesn't actually work that way.  According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html), the annotation "Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection ...at the point when the collection is **retrieved**."

So the annotation affects the result of the query (find), but does not dictate the order in the collection you store the result set into.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I do not understand the javadoc this way. Could You provide an example, how to retrieve the Collection Elements? As I understood, the @OrderBy annotation does not enforce any order of entities to the database. But when retrieved, they are inserted into the collection (List) in the specified order. Look to the main class at the end. one = service.find(one.getId()); (basically em.find(One.class, id);) So I do retrieve the entities.

Comment: As stated, JPA will retrieve the list from the database using the orderby field as you've defined.  It does not maintain the ordering in your entity though, so it is up to your application maintain this ordering when adding new elements.  Every query or find call does not neccessarily go to the database due to entity caching, so you must maintain this list at all times or expect issues like this to arise.  You can force the list to be reloaded by calling em.refresh, but it is more efficient to just maintain your collection ordering.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I understand your comment and the docs. But the comment does not apply to my example code. Please look at it again. I insert two `Many` entities to the the many-relationship of the entity `One`. Then I persist `One` and retrieve it again. Now the many-relationship-list should be ordered. But it is not. Calling refresh has no effect. I have no clue whats going wrong here or how to narrow the problem.